# Why is the isalpha declaration giving me an error code

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to use the `isalpha` function from the `<ctype.h>` library. I have used other functions from other libraries in different files but I cant get `isalpha` to work. The error is:

```
test.c:9:21: error: expected ')'
    int isalpha(int c);
                ^
```

The code I'm working on:

```
// Function Declarations
int isalpha(int c);

int main(void) {
    char letter = get_char("Letter:");
    bool yesno = isalpha(letter);

    if (yesno == true) {
        printf("True\n");
    } else {
        printf("False\n");
    }
}
```

The Library is included in the header I just didn't know how to include the header here.

Thanks for the help

Comment: `isalpha(letter) = bool yesno;` ==> `bool yesno = isalpha(letter);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesnt seem to fix the error code mentioned in the post. The issue seems to be somewhere in collum 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just include `<ctype.h>` and not redefine `isalpha` with an explicit prototype in your code. The reason you get an error is `isalpha()` is probably defined as a macro in `<ctype.h>` and this macro gets expanded as the compiler parses your prototype and the result of the expansion is a syntax error.

Note also that `isalpha()` should not be called with an argument of type `char` because it has undefined behavior for negative values on platforms where `char` is signed by default. Cast `char` arguments as `(unsigned char)` to avoid this undefined behavior.

Furthermore, the return value of `isalpha` is an `int` and the value `0` means false and any other value means true. Comparing `isalpha(letter) == true` is incorrect. Your code relies on the boolean conversion between `int` and `bool`, which is available since C99, but it is error prone to rely on this implicit conversion as this subtlety is probably beyond your skill level.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void) {
    char letter = get_char("Letter:");

    if (isalpha((unsigned char)letter) {
        printf("True\n");
    } else {
        printf("False\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `isalpha` may be declared (not defined or redefined) by a C program as long as `<ctype.h>` is **not** included. This is stated in C 2018 7.1.4 2.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That's technically true, but beginners would be well advised to include `<ctype.h>` and **not** define standard functions themselves.